# Object DML of MERGE INTO in PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, dml

Object DML of Update:

```
UPDATE DEPARTMENTS d
SET d=NEW OBJ_DEPARTMENT(1, 'Information Technology')
WHERE d.OBJECT_VALUE=(
    SELECT VALUE(d)
    FROM DEPARTMENTS d
    WHERE ROWNUM=1
);
```

Object DML of Insert:

```
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS d
VALUES(NEW OBJ_DEPARTMENT(1, 'Information Technology'));
```

Object DML of Delete:

```
DELETE FROM DEPARTMENTS d
WHERE d.OBJECT_VALUE=NEW OBJ_DEPARTMENT(1, 'Information Technology');
```

What would be the syntax of Object DML of MERGE INTO where the destination is an **object table** and the source is a **nested table of objects**?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE OBJECT TYPE OBJ_DEPARTMENT IS OBJECT(
    DEPARTMENT_ID INTEGER,
    DEPARTMENT VARCHAR2(2000)
);
/
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENTS OF OBJ_DEPARTMENT(
    CONSTRAINT PK_DEPARTMENTS PRIMARY KEY(DEPARTMENT_ID)
);
/
```

Comment: This looks more like a homework assignment or self-study problem to me. In real world (read industry) use of objects as schema columns is strongly discouraged as you spend your whole life trying to nesting and unnesting these objects. This is a good feature but nobody uses it in practice. Try to normalize as much as possible instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new collection of OBJ_DEPARTMENT, populate it in PL/SQL, and use the `table` operator to access that collection in a SQL statement.

This example shows the existing row, Information Technology, getting changed to Humand Resources, and the new row, Accounting, being inserted.

```
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENTS d
VALUES(NEW OBJ_DEPARTMENT(1, 'Information Technology'));


CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE OBJ_DEPARTMENT_TAB IS TABLE OF OBJ_DEPARTMENT;
/

declare
    obj_departments obj_department_tab := obj_department_tab(
        obj_department(1, 'Human Resources'),
        obj_department(2, 'Accounting')
    );
begin
    merge into departments old_departments
    using
    (
        select * from table(obj_departments)
    ) new_departments
    on (old_departments.department_id = new_departments.department_id)
    when matched then update
        set old_departments.department = new_departments.department
    when not matched then insert
        values(new_departments.department_id, new_departments.department);
end;
/

select * from departments;

DEPARTMENT_ID   DEPARTMENT
-------------   ----------
1               Human Resources
2               Accounting
```